# Android : Listen to packet data when Android in sleep mode

Tags: android, tcp, cpu, sleep

As stated in the answer to a previous question, the CDMA and GSM radios are kept on, even after the CPU is put to sleep on an Android device. 
My questions are...

1. When a call is received, what is it that wakes the CPU / phone up ?
2. Is there a similar mechanism to wake my application up when data is received via an active TCP connection to a server, even after the phone has gone to sleep mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data cannot be received when the CPU is asleep.

The CPU needs to be woken up once in a while to see if there is new data.  In your code to check for the new data, if there is new data, you can stay awake and go off and do your processing.

You definitely want to learn about BroadcastReceiver and android alarms.  Basically, you can tell Android to send you an Alarm every 5 minutes or whatever, even if it is sleeping.  Your BroadcastReceiver wakes up the CPU when it gets the alarm from android, and stays awake long enough to check if you have new data, or whatever you are trying to do.  If you have new data, you can then tell the CPU to stay awake and you can go off and process your new data.

Here is a [reasonable tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks/).  And of course the Android Developer docs are helpful.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. "The CPU needs to be woken up once in a while to see if there is new data." How do see if there is new data ? I looked in the list of Intents and there is none available for indicating packet data has been received.

Comment: @HeshanPerera ignore sleeping.  Whatever code you would write when you know the phone is awake, you write the same code in your reciever.  Then the alarm wakes up the receiver, the receiver tries to get data if it is there, if it is not the receiver goes back to sleep.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. The thing is, the Android documentation does not talk about an intent that a broadcast receiver could use for this particular case of listening to packet data. Would you happen to be aware of such an intent ?

Comment: how about RRC and baseband processor ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into sending push notifications to your device (if you don't specifically need TCP).

Check out the (free) Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) service from Google (http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/).

It takes a little work to get set up, and is only supported on 2.2+, but really simplifies the client/server architecture.

Comment: I am looking into C2DM as well.. the only drawback is that the device needs to be signed into a Google account. Anyway, it is my understanding that C2DM also runs using the TCP protocol... right ?

Comment: Yeah, under the hood, it uses keep-alive packets to keep the connection to the Google C2DM server. In my experience, it does a pretty good job of maintaining the connection as the user changes connection modes as well (edge -> wifi -> 3g)